since she lived in Glasgow
a. Jane has been getting headaches since she lived in Glasgow.
b. Jane has been getting headaches since she has lived in Glasgow.
Do these imply that she is still in Glasgow?
Do they imply that she is no longer there?
Do they imply that the headaches started when she went to Glasgow? Could they have started a few months after she went there?
Many thanks

Your fifth line said London. It should be Glasgow.

Thank you both very much, Seowjooheng and Mari-Lou A,. I corrected the post.

To me, (b) implies that she still lives there and that the environment of the city has been the cause of the headaches. (a) could be used if she no longer lives there.

This question is similar. If you search for since present perfect or something similar, there are others. Like most questions about tenses, there isn't a perfect answer, and there's room for variation.

Pace @KateBunting, to me (American), your first one means she doesn’t live there anymore. But I agree that the second one means she does. Oh, re-reading her comment I now see that this may not be too far off her take as well.

No native speaker would use the verb lived there with present perfect in the matrix clause. Downvoted. Instead of trying to guess what an unidiomatic sentence means, it would be better to learn to use English properly.  What do you wish to say?  Give us the facts, and we will give you a sentence, and explain why it is as it is.

@TimR - True, I would be more likely to say since she has been living in Glasgow.

Jane has been getting headaches since living in Glasgow, since it's a bit "wordy" to go for full parallelism: Jane has been getting headaches since she has been living in Glasgow.

If you want to state unambiguously that Jane at this moment is living in Glasgow, and also state that she's been having headaches since moving here, or there, you could use a coordinated sentence structure:

Jane has been living in Glasgow for several months now and ever since moving there she has been suffering from headaches.

This strongly implies that Jane still lives in Glasgow but that meaning is not entailed:

Since moving to Glasgow, Jane has been suffering from headaches.

Jane could have given up on modern medicine and moved to the Amazon.
This version with present perfect continuous in both clauses (a variant of the one Kate suggested in a comment) would also be idiomatic and again strongly imply that Jane still lives in Glasgow:

Since she's been living in Glasgow, Jane has been having headaches.

But because "since" can be understood in a causal sense, that sentence structure  is ambiguous, as shown here, with different verbs:

Since she's been living in Glasgow, Jane has been speaking with a slight brogue. But it should wear off now that she's back home in Alabama.

